# view and action method name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

where does mvc stores the association between action method name and view page name? or who is responsible for checking if the there is a view page with name same as action method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewEngine takes care of all that for you.

Have a gander at [this post](http://www.coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/) about creating your own view engine... it gives you an idea of what's going on behind the scenes.

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 2):

You are the one who specifies the relation between the view and the action. By default, when you `return View();`, ASP.NET MVC assumes that the view name is the same as the action name. You can, however, `return View("About");` which will render the view page **About**.

There is no static checking -- the framework searches for the view at runtime. Therefore, the association is not stored anywhere.